# VSCode Keybinding Snippet: Use TM_SELECTED_TEXT to Remove All Slashes From A Selected String

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, key-bindings, vscode-snippets, vscode-keybinding

How can I use a custom Visual Studio Code snippet to remove slashes (`/`), along with other characters, from a selected piece of code?

When I've created a new object to keybindings.json, it only recognized the plus sign (`+`) :

```
   {
      "key": "ctrl+8",
      "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
      "args": {
         "snippet": "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/['+','\/']//gi}"
      },
   },
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean to remove `+` and `/`? Try `"${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/[+\\/]+//g}"` then

Comment: Yes! Absolutely. Thanks @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
"${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/[+\\/]+//g}"
```

Here, the `[+/]+` character class matches `+` or `/` one or more times.

Note the syntax: you cannot use an array of string literals inside the regex part. You need to escape `/` because the *pattern* is separated from *replacement* and *flags* with a `/` delimiter char. To properly escape `/` here, you need to use double backslash, as the `\` char can be used in this environment to define string escape sequences, and thus to define a single literal backslash you need to use two.